# Where exactly should JDBC URL value be changed?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to run some application and get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for
>   JDBC]Can't start a cloned connection while in manual transaction mode.

I know that I should add the parameter ;SelectMethod=Cursor to your JDBC URL

But I'm having problem understanding where exactly should I change it? Should it be some conf file in JDBC driver folder somewhere? Or can I do it from sql management studio?
Also is there some easy way to determine if and what version of JDBC driver I have?

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Eclipse, Intellij, other? Where's your code? What is your JBDC connection string? What are you doing when you get that message? So many additional details that could be important to know here

Answer (score 2):

You specify the URL when creating your JDBC connection, e.g.:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]",
   username,
   password);
```

Of course you have to replace the stuff in the brackets with your values.

Quite the same is true for every other tool (e.g. IntelliJ, Eclipse) I know of that connects to a DB via JDBC. See e.g. attached screenshot. Here you also specify the connection parameters via the JDBC URL.[image]